# Is there a name for this partial-application--like functional programming technique?

Tags: functional-programming, partial-application

I have a function `f: (a, b, c = 5, d = 0) -> {...}` that takes between 2 and 4 arguments.

I want to pass a "bound" version of this function that always uses the defaults for the last arguments, but uses specific values (say 1 and 2) for the first two arguments. That is, I want `g: () -> f(1, 2)`.

If I were to do partial application, I would get `g': (c = 5, d = 0) -> f(1, 2, c, d)`. That is, partial application wouldn't enforce the zero-argument nature of `g` that I desire, instead giving me `g'` which takes between 0 and 2 arguments.

What is the technique for getting `g` from `f` called, if anything?

Comment: `f` already has the default arguments, so why wouldn't currying `g: () -> f(1, 2)` work for you?

Comment: I do not understand how this question is related to currying. The problem you are describing does not seem to be related to making a function take one argument and return another function, which is what currying is.

Comment: As @murgatroid99 pointed out, this has nothing to do with currying... I think you mean "partial application", which is something a lot of people confuse with currying. I know of no particular name for the technique you're describing.

Comment: @murgatroid99, @pelotom: You guys are right, I was talking about partial application, not currying. How embarassing -_-.

Comment: @Matt Ball I don't understand what you mean. I want `g` to take 0 arguments, instead of between 0 and 2.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I am working in JavaScript. But that should be pretty irrelevant. I know how to _implement_ what I am describing; I just don't know what to call it.

Comment: @Domenic: What Matt means is that the function `g: () -> f(1,2)` takes precisely 0 arguments, not between 0 and 2. (If your language doesn't allow such a definition that's another matter.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes, my point was that I want `g`. But instead, partial application gives me `g'`. What is the name of the technique that gives me `g`?

Comment: @Domenic: "partial application gives me `g'`" — I don't see why that's inevitable. Surely it depends on the language etc.: whether 
"partial application" supports specifying the arity of g, exactly when the default arguments are bound, etc. In any case, perhaps this is your real question: given a function `f(a, b, c=5, d=0)` with optional arguments, what is the function `t(f)(a,b) = f(a,b,5,0)` which takes exactly 2 arguments? Then the `g` you want would just be partial application on `t(f)`. (Or, equivalently, `t(g')` where `g'` is the function with 2 optional arguments you mentioned above.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR thanks for the clarifying remarks; I think you are right on all counts. Please feel free to post that in answer form, along with either a name for the `t` operation or a statement that the `t` operation doesn't have a name that you know of, and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer: it seems that this question has little to do with functional programming or currying or partial application, but is instead precisely about taking a function that takes optional arguments that have defaults, and making a new function with no optional arguments in which the default arguments have been fixed.

Call this conceptual transformation `T`. Assuming for some reason that partial application means that optional arguments remain optional (which need not be universal, but then again, the familiar functional programming languages — Haskell etc. — don't even *have* optional arguments), there are at least two ways to get `g` from `f`.

1. - Take `f: (a, b, c = 5, d = 0) -> {....}` which takes 2 to 4 arguments.
   - Generate the new function `T(f) : (a,b) -> {...}` which takes exactly 2 arguments. That is, `T(f)(a,b) = f(a,b) = f(a,b,5,0)`.
   - Now do partial application on T(f) fixing its two arguments as 1 and 2, and call the resulting function `g`. That is, `g() = T(f)(1,2) = f(1,2) = f(1,2,5,0)`.
2. - Take `f: (a, b, c = 5, d = 0) -> {....}` which takes 2 to 4 arguments.
   - Do partial application on `f` fixing its first two arguments as 1 and 2, and call the resulting function `g'`. That is, `g' : (c=5, d=0) -> f(1, 2, c, d)`. It takes between 0 and 2 arguments.
   - Generate the new function `T(g) : () -> {....}` which takes exactly 0 arguments. That is, `T(g)() = g'() = g'(5, 0) = f(1, 2, 5, 0)`.

In any case, the quandary in the question seems to hinge on `T`, rather than any aspect of functional programming or currying or partial application. I don't know if `T` has enough of a point to have a standard name, but something like "fixing/binding default arguments" should be fine.